# Can you make 2 0 = 1 5?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Can you find a way to make 2 0 = 1 5 by adding any operations or symbols? You can use symbols such as these: +, -, *, !, ^, (). It is not limited to this list.The symbols may be added either between or on the outsides of the numbers provided. You may also concatenate.

I would like to see creative ways to make this work. Good Luck!

P.S. You can not add any other numbers to the equation.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why the "1 1 1 1 = 5" has gotten 22 upvotes, protection by Community, and 7k views and now the OP creates another question and it get's put on hold??? What's the difference?

Comment: @NL628 That is the same thing I was thinking. I literally used the same format, but just different numbers. I hope that the edit that I made will convince people to reopen the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this??

> $2^0 = 1^5$

or

> 20 != 15
> where != means "is not equal to", similar to = meaning "is equal to".

Comment: I don't think the second one is correct - not unless `0! = -3`.  (It doesn't, does it?!?)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry - Ahh - I think your edit corrupted hayoon's second answer

Comment: @YowE3K; maybe, but 20!=15 is completely meaningless, so i assume he meant to type 2-0!=1.5 which is reasonably consistent with his first answer

Comment: @JonMarkPerry it is not meaningless, actually - The != is the nonequal operator, i.e. 20 is not equal to 15.

Comment: @Lolgast; lateral - i like it!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry On a side note, not sure on the official Puzzling.SE conventions (if there are any), but I am personally of the opinion that if you see a "completely meaningless" answer, you should ask for clarification rather than edit it to what you assume he meant (which, in this case, was quite radically different). The answer in this case is completely meaningful for pretty much anyone with programming experience.

Comment: @Lolgast; it's not the law (rule 1: se has no rules), probably advisable in most situations:)

Answer (score 8):

These can also work

> $(2 + 0!)! = 1 + 5$
>  $2 + 0 = \sqrt{-1 + 5}$
>  $.2 + 0 = 1 / 5$

Answer (score 3):

Here's one answer:

> 2 - 0! = 1 ^ 5

Note that:

> The factorial of 0 is 1.

Comment: You know that $2! = 2$. So you may want to remove that **!** to use less symbols.

Comment: Ha ha, good spot, @ibrahimmahrir , thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

> $2 + 0 = 1 / .5$

And another:

> $2^{-0!} = 1 - .5$